# ASP.NET Membership roles with DB2 Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey fellows, just wondering how to configure asp.net membership roles with ISeries DB2 Database ? Do I have to write a custom data provider ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Yes, a custom Data Provider will be the only way to go.

The following is the MSDN samples for writing a custom membership provider

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. Any more replies fellows ?